# How to put vector element next to matrix

Tags: matrices

The code is below. I want B to be printed without brackets arround since it is just one vector element.

```
\begin{equation}
Y = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \textit{\textbf{t}}_{1} \\
    \textit{\textbf{t}}_{2} \\
    \textit{\textbf{t}}_{3} \\
    \textit{\textbf{t}}_{4} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    \textit{\textbf{B}}
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you omit the `\begin{bmatrix}` and `\end{bmatrix}` statements that surround "***B*** ".

In addition, you should consider replacing all `\textit{\textbf{.}}` statements with `\bm{.}` ("bold math"). Do verify for yourself that, say, `\bm{t}_{1}` features much better spacing between the letter `t` and the subscript `1` than `\textit{\textbf{t}}_{1}` does.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment
\usepackage{bm}      % for '\bm' macro

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
Y = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \bm{t}_{1} \\
    \bm{t}_{2} \\
    \bm{t}_{3} \\
    \bm{t}_{4} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \bm{B}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you got there first.  deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, the following is what you want:

```
\begin{equation}  
Y=\begin{bmatrix}  
\textit{\textbf{t}}_{1} \\  
\textit{\textbf{t}}_{2} \\  
\textit{\textbf{t}}_{3} \\  
\textit{\textbf{t}}_{4} \\  
\end{bmatrix}  
\textit{\textbf{B}}  
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Ok now it works :P It appeared on the next line for some reason...

Comment: `\textit` and `\textbf` are designed as text-mode commands and shouldn't be used in math mode. If one needs bold-italic letters in math, it's better to load the `bm` ("bold math") package and to write `\bm{.}` instead of `\textit{\textbf{.}}`.

Comment: @mico I agree with you.  I tried to make the minimal change to what the asker requested to get specifically the effect he was looking for.  It looks to me like his stuff might have come out of some other tool, like LyX for example - sometimes you see that kind of stuff and can't control it.